# Jquery avoid external links

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, attr

[description of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BU7fp.png)

Hello everybody I have a problem and ask you for your help please ,
I have a web-site with dynamically given an Id and href attribute to my link in code

```
$('.portfolio_item').each(function(i) {
        $(this).find('a').attr('href' && 'href*="#"', '#work_' + i);
        $(this).find('.podrt_descr').attr('id', 'work_' + i);
    });
```

and now when I use wordpres I try to add  new link to external site but all 
time when I add link to external site my link get internally link like `#work i` , so can anybody give me advise how to tell my jquery code which I gave on the start avoid external links and work just with internal ,I try to used

```
 $('.portfolio_item').each(function(i) {
        $(this).find('a').attr('href*="#"', '#work_' + i);
        $(this).find('.podrt_descr').attr('id', 'work_' + i);
    });
```

for avoid but it doesnt work so I will highly appreciate any of your suggerstion thank you

Comment: `$(this).find('a[href*="#"]').attr('href', '#work_' + i);`

Comment: unfortunately this solution does't work my link getting broken when I fixed like your offer ,Thank you I add picture maybe You can better understand my problem

Comment: Better to make a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) and explain what is your code and what is the expected code

Comment: @MohamedYousef Using `a[href*="#"]` (the [attribute-contains selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)) will match URLs containing the string "#" in any position, i.e. URLs with a [fragment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier). Any URL can have a fragment, so this doesn't restrict the selection to only internal links.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are misunderstanding the `&&` operator in your example. `a && b` means "if a is [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy), use b; if not, use a". The string `'href'` is truthy, so `'href' && 'href*="#"'` in your code evaluates to the string `'href*="#"'`. This is an invalid argument to jQuery's `.attr` method as special characters like `*` and `"` aren't allowed in attribute names, and when I tried running your code it raised an InvalidCharacterError.

Instead, you can use the [attribute-starts-with selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) `a[href^="#"]` to select only links with a URL beginning with the character `#`. This does not necessarily only match links that are internal - depending on what you consider "internal" to mean - but it might be enough for your context.

Using the attribute-starts-with selector will make your code look like this:

```
$('.portfolio_item').each(function(i) {
    $('body').find('a[href^="#"]').attr('href', '#work_' + i);
    $(this).find('.podrt_descr').attr('id', 'work_' + i);
});
```

If you want to also match links using relative URLs, or links to your own site using absolute URLs, you will need some more logic to handle that. But this might be enough to get you started.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but unfortunately this solution doesn't work  I tried it before and I have library in my project which is conflicted with my code I need solution which one will check if href has #work_i  it will decline it and use external link something like this

Comment: Ok, so what library are you using? What steps have you tried to fix the problem? You need to show us your code and give us more context.